# Resource DATASOURCE rolled back in cleanup of LocalTransactionContainment

Tags: java, database, oracle, websphere, datasource

Im working in a WebSphere Application Server 7, JDK 1.6 and Oracle 11g.

Im always receiving this error when using an ejb.

> [7/1/10 17:12:28:770 BOT] 00000013
>   LocalTranCoor W   WLTC0033W: Resource
>   jdbc/oraDS11 rolled back in cleanup of
>   LocalTransactionContainment. 
>   [7/1/10
>   17:12:28:773 BOT] 00000013
>   LocalTranCoor W   WLTC0032W: One or
>   more local transaction resources were
>   rolled back during the cleanup of a
>   LocalTransactionContainment.

This is how im getting the connection from the datasource in WAS.

```
javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) naming.lookup("DataSource");
conn= ds.getConnection();
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the error message, you are doing some work inside a local transaction and **not committing it**. The uncommitted work gets rolledback by the container at the end of the method (by default).

This answer to [Datasource rollback in WAS6.0](http://www.coderanch.com/t/78076/Websphere/Datasource-rollback-WAS#440373) summarizes all this pretty well and since there is no real point at paraphrasing it, I'm quoting it below.

> A `LocalTransactionContainment` is what
>   you get in the absence of a global
>   (XA) transaction. The message
>   indicates that you performed some
>   local transaction work as part of that
>   containment scope (method or activity
>   session) and then **did not commit**. The
>   default behaviour (controlled by
>   unresolved-action) is to rollback any
>   uncommited work at the end of the
>   scope. You have a number of options:
>
> - Explicitly commit the local transaction
>
>   ```
>   connection.commit(); // after the work has been performed
>   ```
> - Change the data source to use auto-commit
>
>   ```
>   connection.setAutoCommit(true); //
>   ```
>
>   before the connection is used
> - Place the work within a global transaction
>
>   ```
>   Context ic = new InitialContext();
>   UserTransaction ut =
>   (UserTransaction) ic.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
>   ut.begin();
>   // use connection here
>   ut.commit();
>   ```
> - Change the unresolved-action to commit
>     Select the 'Servlets' tab on
>     the deployment descriptor editor and
>     then select the servlet in question.
>     Under 'WebSphere Extensions' and then
>     'Local Transaction' set the
>     'Unresolved Action' to 'Commit' from
>     the drop-down menu.

I'd suggest committing the work explicitly (and reading the whole answer).

Comment: erm.. i've changed the unresolved-action, to commit not roll back (default)... and also, what im doing is a simple select... i dont have to do commit after any select...

The message is appearing after a select..

Comment: @Garis You DO have to commit after a select (as mentioned in the link): *every opened connection has to be commited (or rolledback) explicitly before closing. Even if all you have done with that connection is a SELECT Query.*

Comment: This helped! Thank you! Although connection.commit() or connection.setAutoCommit(true) are easy solutions and could fix the problem at hand. I went with Placing the work within a global transaction i.e @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS). In this way even if the data source implementation changes to ConnectionPoolDataSource or XADataSource where the application code should never call Connection methods commit, rollback, or setAutoCommit(true). It would continue to scale. Also Ref: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurs when table get locked, so you have locked your table in database so release that lock and commit whatever changes you have done.