# Error 500: LocalTransaction rolled-back due to setRollbackOnly

Tags: java, oracle, soap, websphere

I am a java developer. I have a web service deployed in my local version of websphere application server which I know works on my production server.

But when I try and execute the web service on my local using SOAP UI I get...

Error 500: LocalTransaction rolled-back due to setRollbackOnly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode><faultstring>com.myer.item.service.ItemSearchException: A database error has occurred. SQL error code: 6550</faultstring><detail><ns1:fault xmlns:ns1="http://service.item.myer.com"/><ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">mvni1120</ns2:hostname></detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>Error 500: LocalTransaction rolled-back due to setRollbackOnly
```

and then looking at the logs further....

```
[31/07/14 15:11:13:204 EST] 296ae24c InternalGener I DSRA8205I: JDBC driver name  : Oracle JDBC driver
[31/07/14 15:11:13:204 EST] 296ae24c InternalGener I DSRA8206I: JDBC driver version  : 9.2.0.3.0
[31/07/14 15:11:13:470 EST] 296ae24c LocalTranCoor E WLTC0033E: Resource jdbc/rmsDS rolled back in cleanup of unresolved LocalTransactionContainment.
[31/07/14 15:11:13:501 EST] 296ae24c LocalTranCoor E WLTC0032E: One or more resources rolled back. An unresolved LocalTransactionContainment had an unresolved action of rollback.
[31/07/14 15:11:13:501 EST] 296ae24c WebAppTransac E WTRN0043I: LocalTransaction rolled-back due to setRollbackOnly.
[31/07/14 15:11:13:517 EST] 296ae24c WebGroup      E SRVE0026E: [Servlet Error]-[LocalTransaction rolled-back due to setRollbackOnly]: com.ibm.ws.LocalTransaction.RolledbackException
    at com.ibm.ws.LocalTransaction.LocalTranCoordImpl.cleanup(LocalTranCoordImpl.java:1091)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppTransactionCollaborator.postInvoke(WebAppTransactionCollaborator.java:249)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:695)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:208)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.WebAppInvoker.doForward(WebAppInvoker.java:134)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.WebAppInvoker.handleInvocationHook(WebAppInvoker.java:321)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.cache.invocation.CachedInvocation.handleInvocation(CachedInvocation.java:71)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srp.ServletRequestProcessor.dispatchByURI(ServletRequestProcessor.java:246)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.oselistener.OSEListenerDispatcher.service(OSEListener.java:334)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:56)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:652)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:448)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:937)
```

Both my local version of the web server and the production version are pointing at the same database. And the soap ui request works to my production version of the web service.

This makes me think it is a problem with the way I am defining my data source. Can someone please help me with this?

thanks

Comment: ORA-06550 means a PL/SQL error; is there anything else in the log with a more specific Oracle message beyond that? It seems weird to be connecting to your production database from somewhere else. Are you connecting as the same user and executing the same PL/SQL, or is your local version running and calling different code?

Comment: You need to update your Oracle driver to the latest version. I have found a similar post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163636/resource-datasource-rolled-back-in-cleanup-of-localtransactioncontainment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to update your Oracle driver to the latest version.
There is a bug in your version of Oracle JDBC driver, It has been fixed in Oracle 9.0.2.6 driver version.

You can read more: [IBM Support Page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21113363)